# ActiveRecord boolean resets to default on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a boolean field that has a default value of false in the joining table of a has many through relationship: tags and tag lists.

```
add_column :taggings, :tag_visible, :boolean, :default => false
```

The theory is that a tag list can have many tags (and vice versa) but a tags visibility can be turned off/on per tag list.
This is also part of a nested resource: `Document has_one :tag_list`

For the most part this is all working. The default value is set on creation and I am updating each instance with an ajax call.

However when I update the document which includes the tag_list as a token input field it resets all of the tagging's visibility back to false regardless of what it was previously.

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to look at the params passed to update taggings and make sure that the value of `tag_visible` is what you want.

Comment: It is not there, which is ideally what I want. I'd rather this field was untouched by the update.

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like that causes this? What does the ActiveRecord code that causes this look like?

Comment: hmmm, you might be onto something. It would appear from the SQL that tagging records are being deleted and re-inserted. I will look into that, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in my tags token_input setter inside my tag_list model I was deleting and recreating a new record in the tagging model instead of updating it.

old code:

```
self.taggings = Tag.ids_from_tokens(tokens, user_id).each_with_index.map {|t,i| Tagging.new(:tag_id => t, :tag_colour => tag_colours[i % tag_colours.size]) }
```

fix:

```
self.tag_ids = Tag.ids_from_tokens(tokens, user_id)
self.taggings.each_with_index {|t,i| t.update_attributes(:tag_colour => tag_colours[i % tag_colours.size]) }
```